# Develop a login WebApi for user authentication which are stored in either active directory or in database

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication, windows-authentication, jwt

I have a system which has 2 types of users

- Internal users ... Authentication mode is "Windows", they are saved in active directory.
- External users ... Authentication mode is "Forms", they are saved in database AspNetUsers table normally.

I have to develop a LoginApi which receives the username and password then authenticate the user either he is an internal or external user. This Api will be used from a third party (iPad)

My suggested solution is [image]

I don't know, will that idea work? Is there another simpler solution?

I've Googled a lot but all results were around,

1. Pure Token Based Authentication
2. Pure Forms Based Authentication
3. Pure Windows based authentication

Nothing meets exactly what I need! Please support me with details as much as possible.

Comment: This is how I do it for the Backoffice and front facing site of a project I am currently working on. The font facing uses forms auth the backoffice uses AD and I have an extra web api for 3rd party dev to connect that links back to their front facing account.

Comment: @Nkosi: Great! I have implemented both SearchInActiveDirectory and SearchInDatabase both are bool methods, but after a true received, what shall I do? 
my thoughts are to call RSAGenerator.GenerateToken() and send it to user 
which is my method, am I on the right track?!

Comment: Yes. I generate my JWT, do my auditing and such and return that in the response. My custom `class BackOfficeTokenAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter` and `class FrontOfficeAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute` authenticates/authorizes calls from the clients after that.

Comment: Yea I got it, but what if the user had changed his/her password, how will you detect this? how do you mark your token as invalid ?!

Comment: which user, back office or customer?

Comment: any one uses the JWT for auth, I thought both type at your case front and back end, same as mine internal and external

Comment: for now i use short lived tokens. when they try to refresh token after it expires I check a security time stamp that i keep track of in the db for all tokens. if jti is in revoke table then no new tokens will be issued.

Comment: Backoffice => internal, customer => external